# Dealing with object parameters and generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have a the following generic methods:

```
public static string Glue(string prefix, string value)
{
    return String.Format("{0}={1}&", prefix, value);
}

public static string Format<T>(string prefix, T obj) where T : struct
{
    return Glue(prefix, (obj).ToString()); ;
}

public static string Format<T>(string prefix, List<T> obj) where T : struct
{
    return String.Join("",obj.Select(e => Glue(prefix, e.ToString())).ToArray());
}
```

Now I'd like to call them with a parameter that comes in as an `object` and could be a variety of types.

I started writing some code and it started looking like it's going to have a very long if/else sequence:

```
// type of value is object, and newPrefix is string
if (value is int)
{
    return Format(newPrefix, (int)(value));
}
else if (value is double)
{
    return Format(newPrefix, (double)value);
}
...
```

Is there a way of avoiding this long sequence of if/else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated there's not much of a way to make this simpler.  The `Format` method is constrained to only taking value types (structs) which is easy to detect at the call site

```
if (value.GetType().IsValueType) {
  // it's a struct
}
```

But there's no way to then to make the `Format` call happy as you can't provide the `T` type.

What you can do here is change `Format` slightly.  The method call only uses the `ToString` method which is available on all types.  You could remove the `struct` constraint and then call it with the value already in `object` form

```
public static string Format(string prefix, object obj) {
    return Glue(prefix, obj.ToString()); ;
}

if (value.GetType().IsValueType) {
  Format(newPrefix, value);
}
```